# How to find out overlapping groups of consecutive 0s and 1s in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Consider the following simple data frame consisting of a binary column called `status` and other numerical columns eligible for aggregation called `column1` and `column2`

```py
> df
  status  column1 column2
0   1       10       5
1   0       20       4
2   0       30       3
3   1       40       2
4   0       50       1
5   0       60       5
6   0       70       4
7   1       80       3
8   1       90       2
9   1       100      1
10  0       110      5
```

I want to perform aggregation on the numerical columns by creating groups of 1 followed by 0s and 0 followed by 1s in the `status` column thereby bringing in the **overlapping** behaviour. After grouping, the groups that would be formed are (starting from index 0): indices 0 to 2, indices 2 and 3, indices 3 to 6, indices 6 to 9 and indices 9 and 10.
After that, the numerical columns can be aggregated easily at our convenience.

E.g. if we want to perform summation across `column1`: the 5 group sums would be 60, 70, 220, 340 and 210 respectively.

I have tried out countless variations of `df['status'].diff().ne(x).cumsum()` for different values of `x` but I am **unable to handle the situation** arising from the need for overlapping groups.

**Edit**:

Since it wasn't clear what output I wanted because I talked about aggregation in general, let us assume I am interested in computing the `sum` and `median` respectively for `column1` and `column2` across the groups formed as per the above procedure. This would be the expected output.

```py
   column1 column2
0    60.0    4.0
1    70.0    2.5
2    220.0   3.0
3    340.0   2.5
4    210.0   3.0
```

Comment: Could you show us the desired output?  I, for one, find it difficult to determine what you want as an answer.

Comment: @PaulBrennan Added a sample output for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a generic method to compute overlapping groups for arbitrary aggregations, you can use a wrapper to compute all the groups:

```
def cust_group(df, i, n=1):
    m = df['status'].eq(i).rename('group')
    return df.groupby(m.cumsum().mask(m).bfill(limit=n))
    
out = (pd.concat({i: cust_group(df, i)[['column1', 'column2']].sum()
                  for i in df['status'].unique()})
         .sort_index(level='group', kind='stable')
      )
```

Output:

```
         column1  column2
  group                  
0 0.0         10        5
1 1.0         60       12
0 2.0         70        5
1 2.0        220       12
0 5.0        340       10
1 5.0        210        6
```

This generic approach requires more computations but enables to have a varying overlapping depth and to use non-associative aggregation functions:

```
# non-associative median computation
out = (pd.concat({i: cust_group(df, i)[['column1', 'column2']].agg(['sum', 'median'])
                  for i in df['status'].unique()})
         .sort_index(level='group', kind='stable')
      )

        column1        column2       
            sum median     sum median
  group                              
0 0.0        10   10.0       5    5.0
1 1.0        60   20.0      12    4.0
0 2.0        70   35.0       5    2.5
1 2.0       220   55.0      12    3.0
0 5.0       340   85.0      10    2.5
1 5.0       210  105.0       6    3.0


# depth of consecutive initial value = 2
# 0/0/0/1/1/1 results in -/0/0/1/1/1 groups
out = (pd.concat({i: cust_group(df, i, n=2)[['column1', 'column2']].sum()
                  for i in df['status'].unique()})
         .sort_index(level='group', kind='stable')
      )

         column1  column2
  group                  
0 0.0         10        5
1 1.0         60       12
0 2.0         90        9
1 2.0        220       12
0 5.0        400       15  # 60+70+80+90+100
1 5.0        300        8  # 90+100+110
```

Comment: Do note that groups compulsorily consist of 1 followed by 0s and vice-versa. So `01` and `10` are the smallest groups possible. Your code produces an extra group resulting from the first element. However, can be removed trivially as it is the first group.

Comment: @PronoyMandal yes, I wasn't sure whether it was an important constraint, but as you said it's easy to remove ;)

Comment: any way to modify the custom grouping function so that apart from the type of groups mentioned in the question, groups consisting of (multiple 1s) and 0 and (multiple 0s) and 1 can also be figured out while following the same overlap behaviour?

Comment: @PronoyMandal not sure I follow you but if I understood removing the `limit=n` might be what you want

Comment: `limit=n` primarily handles the amount of overlap as you have shown in your second example. What I am asking for is the ability to recognise the groups `111...10` and `000...01` alongside the groups mentioned in the question (`1000...0` and `0111...1`).

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'status': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
         'column1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110], 
         'column2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Code**

make grouper(Numbers that are consecutive and the same are divided into the same group.)

```
grp = df['status'].ne(df['status'].shift()).cumsum()
```

`df & grp`

```
                 df                 grp
    status  column1 column2         
0   1       10      5               1
1   0       20      4               2
2   0       30      3               2
3   1       40      2               3
4   0       50      1               4
5   0       60      5               4
6   0       70      4               4
7   1       80      3               5
8   1       90      2               5
9   1       100     1               5
10  0       110     5               6
```

First, let's perform groupby + sum based on the grouper. Then, let's add the last values of the previous group.

column1 :

```
df.groupby(grp)['column1'].sum() + df.groupby(grp)['column1'].last().shift()
```

output :

```
status
1      NaN
2     60.0
3     70.0
4    220.0
5    340.0
6    210.0
Name: column1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is a nice trick for associative aggregations ;) (this wouldn't however enable more complex aggregations like mean/std/… as associativity is required)

Comment: @mozway  I think it would be enough to aggregate `list` and apply the aggregate function.

Comment: But that would be non vectorized

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat((df['status'].diff(-1).ne(0)).add(1))[1:-1]]

df2.groupby([df2.index.to_series().diff().eq(0).cumsum()]).agg({'column1':'sum','column2':'mean'})
```

Output:

```
   column1  column2
0       60      4.0
1       70      2.5
2      220      3.0
3      340      2.5
4      210      3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'status': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                       'column1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110],
                       'column2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]})
    
    # Efficient group creation with boolean operations and cumsum
shifts = df['status'].shift(1).fillna(1)  # Get shifted status with default 1
df['shifts'] =shifts
changes = df['status'].ne(shifts)  # Identify status changes (0->1 or 1->0)
df['changes'] = changes
changes1 = ~changes
df['changes1'] = changes1
groups = changes.cumsum().mask(~changes)  # Group based on changes, gaps filled with previous group
df['group'] = groups.astype(str)  # Convert groups for concatenation
groups1 = changes.cumsum().mask(changes)
df['group1'] = groups1.astype(str)
print(df.to_string())
"""
    status  column1  column2  shifts  changes  changes1 group group1
0        1       10        5     1.0    False      True   nan    0.0
1        0       20        4     1.0     True     False   1.0    nan
2        0       30        3     0.0    False      True   nan    1.0
3        1       40        2     0.0     True     False   2.0    nan
4        0       50        1     1.0     True     False   3.0    nan
5        0       60        5     0.0    False      True   nan    3.0
6        0       70        4     0.0    False      True   nan    3.0
7        1       80        3     0.0     True     False   4.0    nan
8        1       90        2     1.0    False      True   nan    4.0
9        1      100        1     1.0    False      True   nan    4.0
10       0      110        5     1.0     True     False   5.0    nan
"""
filtered_df = df[df['group'] != 'nan']
result = filtered_df.groupby('group')[['column1', 'column2']].agg(['sum', 'median'])
    
print(result)
```

Or Do you want this one ?? :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'status': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   'column1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110],
                   'column2': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]})



changes = df['status'].diff().fillna(0).abs()
df['changes'] = changes
groups = df['status'].groupby((changes != 0 ).cumsum()).transform('idxmin')
df['groups'] =groups

print(df.to_string())
"""    status  column1  column2  changes  groups
0        1       10        5      0.0       0
1        0       20        4      1.0       1
2        0       30        3      0.0       1
3        1       40        2      1.0       3
4        0       50        1      1.0       4
5        0       60        5      0.0       4
6        0       70        4      0.0       4
7        1       80        3      1.0       7
8        1       90        2      0.0       7
9        1      100        1      0.0       7
10       0      110        5      1.0      10
"""

res = df[df['groups'] != 'nan'].groupby('groups')[['column1','column2']].agg(['sum','median'])
print(res)
"""      column1        column2       
           sum median     sum median
groups                              
0           10   10.0       5    5.0
1           50   25.0       7    3.5
3           40   40.0       2    2.0
4          180   60.0      10    4.0
7          270   90.0       6    2.0
10         110  110.0       5    5.0
"""
```